# How to get the selected item from this ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom List view and I been trying to get to next screen if user clicks an item. It doesn't seem to work. I tried if else, switch. It works if I don't use either but that way, every item will go to the same screen. Any help would be appericiated.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options_main);

    OptionMainHeader option_list[] = new OptionMainHeader[]
    {
        new OptionMainHeader(R.drawable.clock_icon_48, "Helo"),
        new OptionMainHeader(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Apple"),
        new OptionMainHeader(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Mango"),
        new OptionMainHeader(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Banana"),

        };

    OptionMainHeader1 adapter = new OptionMainHeader1(this, R.layout.option_main_header1, option_list);

    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.option_main_header, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            int position = listView1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String selectedFromList =(String) (listView1.getItemAtPosition(position));

            if (selectedFromList == "Helo"){
                Intent CurrentWaitTime = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), go.class);
                startActivity(CurrentWaitTime);
            } else if (selectedFromList == "Apple"){
                Intent Appointments = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), no.class);
                startActivity(Appointments);
            } else if (selectedFromList == "Mango"){
                Intent Logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), go.class);
                startActivity(Logout);
            } else if (selectedFromList == "Banana"){
                Intent Exit = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), low.class);
                startActivity(Exit);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You can't compare Strings with "==". What you need to do is use the method equals(String)

Comment: @gian1200 better yet, he should put the strings in the string.xml file and use enums for the values. this way he could also use switch-case, and reduce code writing .

Comment: `getItemAtPosition()` shouldn't return an `OptionMainHeader`? If it returns an `OptionMainHeader`, isn't your cast `String selectedFromList =(String) (listView1.getItemAtPosition(position));` wrong? Can you post the LogCat message to check the reason of the crash?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Strings with "==". What you need to do is use the method String.equals(String). Something like:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selectedFromList = option_list[position].getTHATSTRING();
    if (selectedFromList.equals("Helo")){
        Intent CurrentWaitTime = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), go.class);
        startActivity(CurrentWaitTime);
    } else if (selectedFromLis.equals("Apple")){
        Intent Appointments = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), no.class);
        startActivity(Appointments);
    } else if (selectedFromList.equals("Mango")){
        Intent Logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), go.class);
        startActivity(Logout);
    } else if (selectedFromList.equals("Banana")){
        Intent Exit = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), low.class);
        startActivity(Exit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I don't think there is a need for getSelectedItemPosition since your 3rd parameter to onItemClick is your position (you have it named arg2)

Comment: @AndrewG is right, and that's the *real* cause of his problem. Since nothing is selected, `position` is `INVALID_POSITION` (defined as `-1`) and `getItemAtPosition` won't give anything sensible. Simply using the correct argument should solve it.

Comment: Edited :) didn't notice that part. But he also need to use `equals`

Comment: I think I know what is your problem. Did you override the `getItem` method in the adapter class (in your case `OptionMainHeader1`)? and if so, what are you returning?

Comment: I override the View getview function.

Comment: you need to override  `getItem` in your `OptionMainHeader1` if you want to use the method `getItemAtPosition(position)` since it internally calls `getItem(position)`. If you don't do it, you will always get `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
 TextView textView = (TextView) arg1;
String strText = textView.getText().toString();
       if ("Helo".equals(strText)){
           Intent CurrentWaitTime = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), go.class);
           startActivity(CurrentWaitTime);
    } else if ("Apple".equals(strText){
            Intent Appointments = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), no.class);
            startActivity(Appointments);
        } etc, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you.

```
   listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {

        //global variable
        idItem = (int) id;

        switch (idItem) {

       case 0:
      // This is your first Item

      // Add your Intent and startActivity
   break;

       case 1:
   // Add your Intent and startActivity
   break;

       case 2:
   // Add your Intent and startActivity

   break;

       case 3:
   // Add your Intent and startActivity

   break;
       }

        }
    });
```

You get over id the item you clicked. Then you can go to the right activity you want for this item.
Hope it helps.